# Does a wordpress plugin (not a membership one) exist for selling access to some webpages?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, e-commerce

I am looking for a wordpress plugin in order to sell the access of some webpages on my website. I mean I am not looking for a "membership" plugin.

I mean the user has to pay in order to view the page.
The user also has to pay again, if he wants to view a second paid page. And he has to paid a third time if he wants to see a third paid page, etc.

If he logouts, then he should be able to login later to the website and then to have again access to the pages that he paid for.

I have looked so many plugins that I start wondering if what I want exist ?

I mean I have looked at s2member, Paid Membership Pro, etc. 
But this is all about "Membership": you have to create 1 specific "Membership Level" for each page you want to sell ! What about if you have 1000 pages and you want that the access to each of those pages costs 20EUR ?

If any of you have an idea.. (even if i have to paid to get the plugin).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

With s2Member, you can forget about the membership levels and sell access to individual pages/posts, too.

Comment: Please improve your answer. It already got flagged by the system.

Comment: Where can I find information about what is a good answer and what isn't?

Comment: The [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) isn't that bad. But to tell you in a single line, it should answer the question without any link and then go deeper into detail and tell what the actual answer will do to solve the problem. Examples are appreciated. If a question is too short, it should be a comment. If it then becomes the solution it should be extended and moved to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Paid Memberships Pro has a sister plugin that will work with it to add a one time price for individual pages like you are asking for:

https://github.com/strangerstudios/pmpro-addon-packages

Create one free membership level in PMPro. Then use the price field added by the Addon Packages plugin on the edit post page to set a price for that post/page.

Good luck.